# CSOM not retreiving count of items in a list

Tags: jquery, csom, caml

I'm trying to get a count of specific items in a SharePoint 2010 list but I keep getting a count of ALL the items in the list. Here is my code:

```
var clientContext = null;
var web = null;
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(Initialize, "sp.js");
function Initialize()
{
    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    web = clientContext.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("PerStat");
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    var q = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Group' /><Value Type='String'>DHR</Value></Eq></Where></Query><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>";
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(q);
    this.listItems = list.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(listItems, 'Include(Id)');
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onListItemsLoadSuccess), 
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}
function onListItemsLoadSuccess(sender, args) {

    var count = this.listItems.get_count();

    $('#cDPW').text(count);
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Note: I'm using code from an old answer on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the below line

```
var q = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Group' /><Value Type='String'>DHR</Value></Eq></Where></Query><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>";
```

to

```
var q = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Group' /><Value Type='text'>DHR</Value></Eq></Where></Query><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>";
```

You have change the "String" to "text". Please try this and let us know this solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

you need to load List before load Listitem **clientContext.load(list)** and then clientContext.load(listItems, 'Id');